# How do I do this without a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, window-functions

[image]

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM org_type_on_related_genre 
WHERE genre_id = :deletedGenreId 
and org_type_id IN 
(SELECT org_type_id 
 FROM org_type_on_related_genre 
 GROUP BY org_type_id 
 HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

I need to make the same query, but without a subquery!

I need to get the count of rows in which genre_id is equal to the :deletedGenreId and the org_type_id value of this line in this table is not unique

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of the subquery?

Comment: The optimizer should come up with a plan that fits best your query based on the data in your tables, so you should really worry about how you write the query, unless you have some other constraints that we don't know of.

Comment: I was told subqueries have very poor productivity. need to redo without subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with sub-query. Sub-query actually can help boost performance and increase code readability if you do it correctly. It is indispensable for complicated logic.

What we generally want to get rid of is correlated sub-query, like the one in your script.
The following query implement the same logic as yours without correlated sub-query:

```
with dup_org_type as (
select org_type_id
  from org_type_on_related_genre
 group
    by org_type_id
having count(0) > 1 
)
select count(0)
  from org_type_on_related_genre otrg
      ,dup_org_type dup
 where otrg.genre_id = :deletedgenreid
   and otrg.org_type_id = dup.org_type_id
```

If the table is big, there are many different org_type_id, and deletedgenreid is very selective, your script will actually have better performance. It all depends on the volume of data the query needs to touch.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this can be efficiently solved without some kind of subquery or derived table.

Here is an option that still uses a subquery, but with window functions. I would expect that this should be more efficient than your original query, since the table is scaned only once (the second level of querying is more of a syntactical sugar):

```
select count(*) 
from (
    select count(*) over(partition by org_type_id) cnt
    from org_type_on_related_genre 
    where genre_id = :deletedgenreid 
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: @vage: please elaborate on what you mean by *does not work*.

Answer (score 1):

Without a subquery?  I think you can do:

```
select count(*) over ()
from org_type_on_related_genre 
where genre_id = :deletedgenreid 
group by org_type_id
having count(*) > 1
limit 1;
```

That doesn't seem useful, though.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b0a3fb134318e3e07bc2e86a6f8ded10) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @vage . . . This has a db<>fiddle that shows that it *does* work.